# Black line on the lower screen. Macbookpro2017

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

Why is there a black line appearing on the lower part of the screen? It also contains fragments such as letters from websites I visit to. How can I fix this?

Thanks for answering my question in advance

Soo... the problem is now worse than before 
[image]

and later this day (tuesday november 6) this started showing up.

[image]

How much would it cost for me to repair this if it is a retina hardware issue?

The specs of my device is MacOS Mojave version 10.14, 13 inch, 2017, 2.3 GHz Intol Core i5, Intel Iris plus Graphics 640 1536 MB

Comment: maybe if we knew the OS X, and it is difficult to see what line, do you mean the one on top of the menu bar ?

Comment: If it's always there regardless of what is on screen it may be a hardware issue.

Comment: @Buscar웃 There are new problems that have risen and I dont know where to start